# empty folder after connection Motorola G5S Plus to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: usb, nautilus, android, mtp

I have connected my motorola G5S Plus phone to Ubuntu 20.04 PC by USB
and I have installed mtp-tools .

When clicking the phone dock icon, I get an empty folder screen in Nautilus .
The phone is mounted .  Then I choose the option "open in terminal" and entered

`mtp-detect`

This is what was displayed in terminal :

```
libmtp version: 1.1.17

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=22b8 and PID=2e82) is a Motorola Moto G (ID2).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Motorola: Moto G (ID2) (22b8:2e82) @ bus 2, dev 9
Attempting to connect device(s)
error returned by libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

Comment: Some Android phones nowadays have more security implemented. They are required to unlocked after connecting via USB in order to appear in file manager.

Comment: @Kulfy, how am I supposed to do that ?

Comment: By unlocking I mean unlocking screen. Does your mobile phone has password/PIN?

Comment: yes, a PIN code

Comment: but it's open now, still the same thing : "empty folder"

Comment: I used to have a Moto G5. I had to go into the phone settings and select a file transfer method. It will default to "charge only" and refuse connections. And then it will keep switching back to charge-only when you are not looking